# How can we secure our API end points on Firebase functions and provide an authentication method to the users?

Tags: firebase, rest, api, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We are writing some APIs using Firebase functions and like to ensure they are secure.

Below steps are taken to provide an authentication process. Would there be any advantages to requiring each API call to include idTokan in the headers and would it be better than using a simple shared key, stored somewhere?

Our current design is below:

1. Creating a user manually on the back end and providing email/password to the client making API calls.
2. Requiring them to pass email/pass as parameters to an /auth end point and we return them a Firebase idTokan
3. Requiring them to add that idToken in the header of any subsequent call till it's expired which they need to repeat step 2 then

To get idToken on the back-end we would be using [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) to authenticate user using email/password and return them the idToken.

Is there any advantages to this flow compared to a simple shared key? It appears that if an attacker can access the email/pass they can still authenticate.

Studied [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) for restricting IPs, [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) for validating idTokens, and have read quite a few articles but still perplexed!

Comment: This question is very broad and is not a Firebase-specific question. I think you need to focus more on researching about API security best practices first, and then apply that to your Firebase end-points. Firebase is not an air-tight solution, and could still have security risks when not used correctly. Regarding attackers having access to email and password. The harm depends on how the attacker got the information. Was it because of a compromised device or user negligence? Then it is an isolated user-specific case. If it is because of a hole in your code, then you need to patch it up.

Comment: Hi Jo, appreciate your comment. I have been reading on API designs and information on Firebase for months now and I have been using Firebase for 4 years yet this is a question I need to answer. I understand there are other solutions but as the question states, we are interested in finding the best solution using Firebase. So while there might be other ways to go, this question is targeting Firebase. Would also appreciate it if you can elaborate on Firebase's issues that leads you to conclude Firebase solution wouldn't be air-tight. Thank you

Comment: I am not telling you about other solutions, I am telling you that what you need is to understand API security in general. Firebase is a platform, their security is only limited to their service and platform, not to your API or any other back-end code you deploy to Firebase. So if you for example have code that imports/requires a library that has security issues, then your API is vulnerable to those security issues even if you do use Firebase. Using Firebase does not mean you will be risk-free, what you need is to understand Server/API security in general, which is very broad.

Comment: Thanks Jo for the comments. True that API vulnerability depends on the packages used but I honestly don't know how that is related to this question. As far as I know, no matter where you create your APIs if your dependencies have vulnerability you cannot fully escape them. All I am trying to ask here is how to deal with authentication if we were to build a range of APIs on Firebase and specifically how would having a shared key be different than using email/pass and use Firebase idTokans. Thanks again